# Composer require apigility cant find package bshaffer/oauth2-server-php:dev-develop even though it's clearly on packagist

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

Im trying to install apigility on top of my current zf2 skeleton project. I ran `composer require zfcampus/zf-apigility:dev-master --prefer-dist -vvv` and I get `zfcampus/zf-apigility dev-master requires bshaffer/oauth2-server-php dev-develop -> no matching package found.` The package and version tag match what's on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php). I tried turning on "minimum-stability": "dev" in my own composer.json but got the same result. How can I get composer to resolve this?

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include a bunch of other packages for the installation to succeed, since Apigility is not a single package:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.8",
    "bshaffer/oauth2-server-php": "dev-develop",
    "rwoverdijk/assetmanager": "~1.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.3-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-apigility": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-apigility-provider": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-api-problem": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-content-validation": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-hal": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-mvc-auth": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-oauth2": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-rest": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-rpc": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-versioning": "~1.0-dev"
},
"require-dev": {
    "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-configuration": "~1.0-dev",
    "zfcampus/zf-apigility-welcome": "~1.0-dev"
}
```

Try including the missing packages from above and/or update the ones you already have with the versions above.